# Can I get Google maps to show our branch location on the embedded map without zooming in?

Tags: seo, local-seo, google-maps, google-my-business

I have a listing of bank's branch done. But I can't see that on normal map unless zoomed in to that particular location, whereas other locations can be even seen without zooming in.

Can anyone please explain me the algorithm behind it? Is there a way I can show my listing without zooming in?